# GLFW_TRANSPARENT and GLFW_ALPHA_MASK are undefined

Tags: opengl, glfw

I've installed [glfw](https://www.nuget.org/packages/glfw/3.2.1.5/) and [nuopengl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nupengl.core/0.1.0.1), so far everything is fine but I want to make my window's background transparent.

From what I've searched, people seem to use `GLFW_TRANSPARENT` or `GLFW_ALPHA_MASK` but those aren't declared in my libraries.

Opening `GLFW/glfw3.h` shows that the version is `3.2` and my OpenGL (nupengl) version is `0.1.0.1`.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT, GL_TRUE);
--- OR ---
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_ALPHA_MASK, GL_TRUE);
```

Both are undefined, yet it seems to work for other people?

Error is just:

```
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "GLFW_GLFW_ALPHA_MASK" is undefined   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "GLFW_TRANSPARENT" is undefined
```

Comment: First thing to check would be a verification for actually having those defines in your header file.

Comment: @SergeyA I wasn't able to find declaration for either of those.